# How to use lambda expression in android

Tags: android, lambda, android-gradle-plugin

I'm having this error when trying to use lambda expressions.

Error:

> Error:(122, 42) error: lambda expressions are not supported in -source 1.7
>   (use -source 8 or higher to enable lambda expressions)

How can I solve it notice that my android studio is 3.0

Comment: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Its because maybe you are using Java 7 and Actually, `Retrolambda` is a library which we can use with `Java 8 lambda expressions`.

**So How To SetUp :-**

Add this following to your **`project’s main build.gradle`**

```
 classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.2.3'
```

then add this to **`your application module’s build.gradle`**

```
apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'
```

then we need to add these lines to **`your application module’s build.gradle`**

```
android {
  compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}
```

and done, you can use it like below :-

> eg.) Clicking a button with Retrolambda.

```
  // RETROLAMBDA WAY
        clickMeBtn.setOnClickListener(view ->
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
             "This is the way to click a button to make a toast with RetroLambda !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show());
```

Anonymous class `new View.OnClickListener()` can be replaced with `lambda` .

Comment: @ali-habbash check this answer , hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much it's so helpful and must acceptable answer too for android studio versions  that does not support embedded java 8 yet

Comment: hi @AliHabbash , if it helps you feel free to accept it mate.

Answer (score 22):

Add the below code to your app level gradle:

```
android {
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sanjay.sanjay"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 29
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

}
```

add like this in you app.gradle file in android studio

Answer (score 1):

Add the following block into your app level gradle file inside

`android {}` attribute

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
```

like

```
 android {
...
compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
            targetCompatibility = '1.8'
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use the following code and click the sync button and then your errors will be fixed

```js
android {
  defaultConfig {
    // Required when setting minSdkVersion to 20 or lower
    multiDexEnabled true
  }

  compileOptions {
    // Flag to enable support for the new language APIs
    coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    // Sets Java compatibility to Java 8
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
  }
}

dependencies {
  coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.0.9'
}
```